# To detect [programmatically] documents that are in certain Lifecycle state

Tags: documentum

I want to develop a software that (using DFS) will scan documents on Documentum Content Server and find ones that have a lifecycle attached; and current state of the lifecycle has certain name. Say, ‘ToBeExported’.

Below is DQL query I have created for this:

**select dm_document.r_current_state, dm_document.r_object_id, dm_document.object_name from dm_document where dm_document.r_policy_id is not NULL and dm_document.r_current_state in (select i_state_no from (select dm_policy.i_state_no, dm_policy.state_name from dm_policy where dm_policy.r_object_id=dm_document.r_policy_id) where state_name='ToBeExported')**

The question is: maybe I have missed something; or there is a better way to do it?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would probably work.

But a question arise: why isn't the lifecycle doing whatever work you want to do, by itself ?

Comment: I need to monitor a Documentum Content Server to detect Documents that have come to certain Lifecycle; and then EXPORT them to another document management system.

Comment: I understood that much. But my question remain: Why not change the lifecycle so it does the export itself ?